# Combine two lists by ID

Tags: java, list, kotlin, collections

I have two lists of objects with contents that look like this:

```
List A
id = 1, name = "alex", height = null, weight = 60
id = 2, name = "sara", height = null, weight = 50

List B
id = 1, name = "alex", height = 40, weight = null
id = 2, name = "sara", height = 30, weight = null
```

I can't come up with anything good to "merge" these two lists overriding the nulls. The ideal end result would be:

```
id = 1, name = "alex", height = 40, weight = 60
id = 2, name = "sara", height = 30, weight = 50
```

I've been looking into Kotlin collections to see if there's anything that would help me get closer to this but I have only been able to do this:

```
a.union(b).groupBy { it.id }
```

This returns a map with the ID as key and the full object as value... but I still need to merge the values into one object.

Is there anything that will do this that is not a very manual approach of checking nulls and picking the value in the other list?

Comment: What if there is id=2, name=sarah, height=50 in list 1, and id=2, name=alex, height=70 in list 2? Do you want to keep both of them?

Comment: Collection frameworks will normally not merge their elements but just keep one or the other. You would need to do the merging yourself, e.g. using Java streams (or whatever Kotlin provides).

Comment: Yeah use Java streams api

Comment: Something like `yourList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getId(), e -> e, (a, b) -> merge(a, b))` should do the trick. `merge(a, b)` would get two elements and return a merged version - you'd implement that method and merge by overriding nulls and handling conflicts in any way you need/want. Then convert the map's `values()` collection back to a list.

Comment: @coconut does my answer (down below) work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made the following (using "User" as a placeholder. Replace it with your own data structure):

```
List<User> ul1 = new ArrayList<>();
ul1.add(new User(1, "alex", null, 90));
ul1.add(new User(2, "sara", null, 50));

List<User> ul2 = new ArrayList<>();
ul2.add(new User(1, "alex", 40, null));
ul2.add(new User(2, "sara", 30, null));

List<User> rl = new ArrayList<>(Stream.concat(ul1.stream(), ul2.stream())
                                      .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                              User::getId,
                                              e -> e,
                                              User::merge
                                      )).values());

for (User u : rl) {
    System.out.println(u.toString());
}
```

And this is the "User" class (Replace it with your own Data structure):

```
public static class User {
    private final int id;
    private final String name;
    private final Integer height;
    private final Integer weight;

    public User(int id, String name, Integer height, Integer weight) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.height = height;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Integer getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public Integer getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", height='" + height + '\'' +
                ", weight='" + weight + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public static User merge(User e1, User e2) {
        if (e1.id != e2.id)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        return new User(
                e1.id,
                eval(e1.name, e2.name),
                eval(e1.height, e2.height),
                eval(e1.weight, e2.weight)
        );
    }

    private static <T> T eval(T v1, T v2) {
        return v1 != null ? v1 : v2;
    }
}
```

The result I got was:

```
User{id=1, name='alex', height='40', weight='90'}
User{id=2, name='sara', height='30', weight='50'}
```

So I guess it works